# How do display names relate to at-mentions?

Tags: support, comments, display-name

Display names seem to be able to use full-on Unicode, but this is not so for at-mentions (Comment-replies).
At the very least, spaces are stripped when doing an at-mention for `Test User`; this would become `@TestUser` in a reply comment.

How are display names processed to produce this string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See ["How do comment @replies work?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/148310) and ["@Peter works for Péter Török?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48968/148310).

Comment replies *will* often work with unicode. EG: Péter Török can be reached by both `@Peter` and `@Péter`.

---

These are the *documented* rules (Not checked against latest source) for converting user `display_name` to comment-reply `@names`:

1. Remove any spaces.
2. [Single quotes, dots, dashes and underscores should **not** be removed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51913/148310)
3. [Special characters are replaced with their simple equivalent.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49409/148310)
   The rules for that were last documented in [this answer from Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7696/148310).  For convenience the last posted remap code was:

```c#
public static string RemapInternationalCharToAscii (char c) {
    string s = c.ToString ().ToLowerInvariant ();
    if ("àåáâäãåą".Contains (s) ) {
        return "a";
    } else if ("èéêëę".Contains (s) ) {
        return "e";
    } else if ("ìíîïı".Contains (s) ) {
        return "i";
    } else if ("òóôõöøőð".Contains (s) ) {
        return "o";
    } else if ("ùúûüŭů".Contains (s) ) {
        return "u";
    } else if ("çćčĉ".Contains (s) ) {
        return "c";
    } else if ("żźž".Contains (s) ) {
        return "z";
    } else if ("śşšŝ".Contains (s) ) {
        return "s";
    } else if ("ñń".Contains (s) ) {
        return "n";
    } else if ("ýÿ".Contains (s) ) {
        return "y";
    } else if ("ğĝ".Contains (s) ) {
        return "g";
    } else if (c == 'ř') {
        return "r";
    } else if (c == 'ł') {
        return "l";
    } else if (c == 'đ') {
        return "d";
    } else if (c == 'ß') {
        return "ss";
    } else if (c == 'Þ') {
        return "th";
    } else if (c == 'ĥ') {
        return "h";
    } else if (c == 'ĵ') {
        return "j";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll note to any StackExchange staff reading this post: the comment discussion on Jeff's answer remains seemingly unresolved.  Using the official Unicode translation tables would be a lot better – everyone can implement the same standard :)